# Python Asyncio: How to read properly?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm trying to implement a tcp proxy server.
At first I need to recieve whatever data from a client. Here I got stuck. Seems like `req.read()` can't get **EOF**. So, how do I implemenent it properly?

```py
import asyncio

host, port ='127.0.0.1', 8080

async def on_data(req, resp):
    #data = await req.read() #Hangs until the client ^C
    while not req.at_eof(): # The same^
        data = await req.readline()
        print(data.decode())
        if not data:
            break
    print(req.at_eof())
    resp.write('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 8\r\n\r\nwhatever'.encode('utf-8'))
    await resp.drain()
    resp.close()
    await resp.wait_closed()
    print('DONE')

async def main(host, port):
    server = await asyncio.start_server(
        on_data, host=host, port=port, 
        reuse_address=True, reuse_port=True,
    )
    
    addr = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
    print(f'Serving on {addr}')
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(main(host,port))#,debug=True)
```

Comment: How is this a TCP proxy server, it looks like an HTTP server which is a different thing. An HTTP/1.1 client won't close the connection after sending the request (it will keep the connection to read the response, and also for further requests), which is why you don't read EOF and `req.read()` "hangs". The server must either parse the `Content-Length` header or support the "chunked" transfer encoding. This kind of stuff is best left to specialized software such as [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) which has this implemented and thoroughly debugged.

Comment: what if the server will potentially work not only with http? it is possible in one solution?

Comment: Is what possible, exactly? Read a request and return a response over the same connection? Not if you have no idea how the request is delimited (when it ends) - you just don't know when is the time to stop reading because no more data is about to arrive. (You could wait for some timeout period during which the client didn't send anything, but that will introduce latency to all responses, and fail when the client happens to be slow enough to trigger the timeout while it actually had more data to send.)

Comment: so, the solution is to throw away the idea of implementing http with all other possible protocols?

Comment: I don't understand how that idea was supposed to work in the first place because you never explained it other than dropping hints. Instead of asking further questions in the comments, please edit the question to clarify what it is you're trying to achieve.