# How do I get and then parse raw http response?

Tags: python-3.x, http, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am writing some kind of proxy. It uses **aiohttp** to get requests and then sends them in a raw format by **asyncio**.
I am using **asyncio** here because **aiohttp** as far as I know does not support sending raw requests.
**For my purposes** I need to get raw response from the server and then send it back to the aiohttp client. But here I face **2 problems**:

1. aiohttp can send only **parsed** form of response via web.Response. And
2. **asyncio** can't just read the **http** response ( as was described here: [Python Asyncio: How to read properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65331425/python-asyncio-how-to-read-properly) ).
   To solve the second problem I could write some kind of dirty solution for **Content-Length** header:

```py
headers = await reader.readuntil(CRLF*2)
#then get Content-Length header
if has_body:
  body = await reader.read(length_of_body)
```

but potentially I can meet **Transfer-Encoding**.

How do I solve this? Any other solutions are welcome.

**UPDATE:** I looked at http.client.HTTPResponse, urllib3.response.HTTPResponse which take **socket** , but no success so far. I can't get anything from them.
That's all because of **Connection: keep-alive** header, which doesn't let the remote server to close the connection, so **asyncio** just hangs.

**What I need:** to send a raw request and to get a raw response immediately. Somehow

**my SOLUTION:** (so far). As my proxy is aimed to detect all kinds of wierdness, I need to get all data from the socket. So, there are 2 ways.

One is the connection is being made with **Connection: keep-alive** header. In this case we dirty-check the raw request by regex `re.compile('\sConnection\s*:\s+keep-alive\b',re.I)` to detect if it should be kept alive. Then we `reader.read(1)` until the connection is closed simultaniously returning current read data.
And the second, when the connection will be closed, we just `reader.read()`.

Any ways to improve or add smth?

Comment: Note that `reader.read(n)` can return less than `n` bytes. You probably want `reader.readexactly(length_of_body)`.

Comment: I think self implemented solution from above is rather too dirty. I'm trying to avoid it.

Comment: Agreed - I was just pointing out the semantics of `read()` unrelated to your actual question. Your question is interesting and I upvoted it. Unfortunately I don't know of a library that provides the functionality of reading an HTTP request while providing it in raw form. You might actually need to implement it yourself.

Comment: so, the thing is that with **reader.read()** I actually get what I want. But it hangs as the connection is being open. Even with reading by 1 **reader.read(1)** and close on ```data==b''``` it still hangs.

Comment: In my second comment by `read()` I meant "a function named `read`" (the `()` suffix indicates a function by convention) without meaning to imply a call without arguments. In other words, my first comment was only about the semantics of `reader.read(length)`, which doesn't do what you need to process `Content-Length` (it can return less data) - you need `reader.readexactly(length)` instead. And I understand that ideally you'd like to avoid implementing the transfer part of HTTP.